# Get last auto inserted ID in identity column from DB Using Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, identity

I am using below code to get new inserted ID in auto identity column from database.

```
using (TestEntities entities = new TestEntities())
{
    T2 t2 = new T2();
    t2.Value = "some value";
    entities.AddToT2(t2);
    entities.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine(t2.ID);

}
```

It's working fine when I connect my application with MS Sql, but if I connect with Mysql, it always returns 0 (zero).

Is there any other way to get last inserted ID using Entity Framework?

Thanks...

Comment: Talk to whoever wrote your MySQL driver? EF certainly supports this; your driver may or may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got soln. The table I was inserting row had only one column - 'ID' with auto identity = true. When I add one more nullable column with any name in table It's start working with my sql too!!! I think the problem is in my sql connector and not in entity framework.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the Identity Mechanism to get the ID of an inserted record after SaveChanges().  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the Telerik OpenAccess ORM.

Open the Entity Model diagram in Visual Studio.
Right-click on the table of interest and select Properties.
Verify the Identity Mechanism property is set to DatabaseServerCalculated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get last Auto inserted ID using SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); or SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

for mySQL:

```
var sql = "Insert t2(item) Values (value); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); ";
int ID = entities.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).Single();
```

For SQLServer, using:

```
var sql = "Insert t2(item) Values (value); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ";  
int ID = entities.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).Single();
```

---

```
//Version Info.:
//EntityFramework (Microsoft) Version=6.2.0 
//MySQL.Data (Oracle) v8.0.12
//MySQL.Data.EntityFramework (Oracle) v.8.0.12
```

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted the line to "entities.T2.Add(t2);" in Vatsal Desai's code and it works fine.

```
//Version Info.:
//EntityFramework (Microsoft) Version=6.2.0 
//MySQL.Data (Oracle) v8.0.12
//MySQL.Data.EntityFramework (Oracle) v.8.0.12

using (TestEntities entities = new TestEntities())
{
    T2 t2 = new T2();
    t2.Value = "some value";

    entities.T2.Add(t2);

    entities.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine(t2.ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can get the last inserted ID of an auto-increment field by using

**For MySQL only**

```
SELECT last_insert_id() as Last_ID
```

That will work **assuming** Entity Framework uses SQL to drive the MySQL database.
A simple test will answer that I guess.

Note that you will only get the last inserted ID from the **current connection** (which is usually what you want).
There is no way (that I know of) to get last inserted id of other connections, other than
doing a

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM sometable as Last_ID
```

Which will work if the insert from the other connection has been committed.

**Making it portable to other DB's**
If you want to make this solution portable to *other* DB's you can make a stored function like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetLastID: integer; 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE lastid: integer; 

  SELECT last_insert_id() INTO lastid; 
  RETURN lastid; 
END;
```

Then you can change that stored procedure should you change DB-backend.
With no need to rewrite any other code.

SELECT GetLastID() as Last_ID

Comment: Join, I don't think "Select Max(ID)..." will work all time. I can't use it. I also posted this issue on MySql site's forum but not get response yet. At the same time I am continuously working on this issue. Hope will get soln soon. It's very important for our project...

Comment: Yes that will work but only with MySQL, right? My application requirement is to make generic solution because it's my company's product and I don't know the client going to use which database with this application. So... the solution must be generic :). btw, thanks for your interest in my problem...

Comment: Yep, you did TAG it with MySQL though. If you make a stored function named `GetLastID: integer BEGIN declare lastid: integer; select last_insert_id() into lastid; return lastid; END;` Then you can change that stored procedure should you change DB-backend. With no need to rewrite any **other** code.

Comment: Hmmm... SP is one of the good option but we are not using SPs in our data access layer, so I have to discuss this with others in my company. At the same time still I think that SP is not complete solution b'cos I have to change in SP each time I change database in back end.

Comment: @Vatsal How many times do you change the database backend? Daily?

Comment: Finally I got soln. The table I was inserting row had only one column - 'ID' with auto identity = true. When I add one more nullable column with any name in table It's start working with my sql too!!! I think the problem is in my sql connector and not in entity framework. Thanks :)